# "Get Started" postback call being received twice in facebook bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a facebook messenger bot.

When the user clicks on "Get Started" button in the messenger, my nodejs application receives the postback event twice instead of once.

I am specifically referring to this event :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button

Any clue why this could be happening ?

The events I am subscribed to are as below:

[image]

NOTE:

I do not receive the postback event twice if I send a empty 200 status message

```
           case 'action@getStartedButton':
                 console.log('sending response');
                 const senderID = event.sender.id;
                 client.sendMessage(senderID, {
                    text: 'Hello!',
                  });
                 res.send(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn of the 'message_echoes' event subscription from web hook.

Here is the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook

Comment: Not subscribed to message_echoes. I also do not receive the event twice if I send a empty 200 message

Comment: This is expected behavior. You need to respond to all webhook events with a 200OK, otherwise the Platform will retry until it gets the 200 response from your webhook.